# after re-instantiating another python Selenium Webdriver 2nd time to call .get() function to open a scraped url. It does not go to the correct url?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

So doing this works for a previously scraped url, but not the next. It fills in the new url in the browser - I can see this , but then undoes it and overwrites with the website's homepage...

Btw I have tried ALL types of Implicit and explicit Waits, I have the window maximized beforehand. I have tried to do a button click instead , also with the WaitUntilElementisClickable() type of wait with 5-7 seconds even - no luck.

Its a pretty secure website - sports betting. So many proxy servers Im going through randomly also...

Any ideas ?

here is a code snippet :

try:
#test_wrongPg_mls_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Game Lines')))
# mls_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_visible((By.LINK_TEXT, 'USA - MLS')))
mls_btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Soccer')
except TimeoutException as e:
print("[{}] Element not clickable".format(str(datetime.now())))

```
                    time.sleep(wait_time35)
                    time.sleep(wait_time35)

                    matches_pg_url = mls_btn.get_attribute('href')

                ############################
                    driver.quit()
                    proxies = req_proxy.get_proxy_list()
                    PROXY_COUNTER = random.randint(1, len(proxies))

                    PROXY = proxies[PROXY_COUNTER].get_address()
                    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
                        "httpProxy":PROXY,
                        "ftpProxy":PROXY,
                        "sslProxy":PROXY,
                        "proxyType":"MANUAL",
                    }
                    driver_1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
                    driver_1.maximize_window()
                        
                    time.sleep(wait_time12)
                    time.sleep(wait_time12)

                    driver_1.get(matches_pg_url) 
                    randFloatNUm5_7 = random.SystemRandom().uniform(5, 7)
                    time.sleep(randFloatNUm5_7)

                    # if len(driver.window_handles) > 0 :
                    #     window_after = driver.window_handles[-1]
                    #     driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

#driver.refresh()
time.sleep(wait_time12)
try:
usa_btn = driver_1.find_element_by_partial_link_text('USA')
except TimeoutException as e:
print("[{}] Element not clickable".format(str(datetime.now())))

```
                    #usa_btn = WebDriverWait(driver_1, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'USA')))
                    time.sleep(wait_time12)
                    matches_pg_url_usa = usa_btn.get_attribute('href')

                    driver_1.quit()
                    PROXY = proxies[PROXY_COUNTER].get_address()
                    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
                    "httpProxy":PROXY,
                    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
                    "sslProxy":PROXY,
                    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
                    }
                    driver_2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
                    driver_2.maximize_window()
                    time.sleep(wait_time35)
                    time.sleep(wait_time12)
                    time.sleep(wait_time35)
                    driver_2.get(matches_pg_url_usa)
```

So the first re-instantiatedDriver and its get work fine, but not the next one... - i.e on the final line it does not navigate to the correct url (which exists!)

Comment: does anyone have a n answer here -  pleaaase , tried everything and really stuck ! calling all Selenium and webdriver Expeeerts !!! :)

Comment: Hello StackOverflow - has anyone come across this issue before !??! :)